# Why does my viewmodel name have to be 'model'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been working with MVC for quite a while. I made a form to submit my data using an entity model and as per requirement had to add tags too so I updated the view and the actionmethod to use a viewmodel instead. Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PostwTagsVM post)
{
}
```

Surprisingly, the model was null.I couldn't find out why but then decided to rename the object as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PostwTagsVM model)
{
}
```

Surprisingly, I get the data in the model now.
I know I can work like this but if i really needed to name by model object something else other than 'model'. Whats happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have to be named `model`.

If in the first case, your model is `null`, its because your `PostwTagsVM` model contains a property named `post`.

The parameter can be named whatever you want, except that it cannot be the same name as one of the properties in your model.

The reason is that your form would be sending back a name/value pair that is (say) `post=someValue`. The `DefaultModelBinder` looks for a matching name, sets the value of the property named `Post` to `someValue`, but then also finds a parameter named `post` and tries to set that to `someValue`, which fails (because you cannot do `PostwTagsVM post = "someValue";`), and the model becomes `null`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. New concept in my pocket.